# Can I use a USB attached Hard Drive on Win7 for TimeMachine backup?

Tags: mac, external-hard-drive, nas, time-machine

I have a Western Digital external USB hard drive. I would like to use this as my Time Machine backup HDD for my new MacBook. After a bit of research I've found that I can't simply share the HDD via my Windows 7 desktop - the HDD must be considered an NAS.

Is there any utility out there that would allow me to *trick* computers on my home network into thinking that the USB HDD hooked up to my Win 7 machine is a NAS? Essentially, I need to publish a USB HDD to the network as a NAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `NAS` is a network attached storage that really doesn't need to be 'faked',

This should help you tho: [Time Machine/Time Capsule with a Windows 7 share disk](http://andreslopez.us/blog/?p=53)

Comment: I understand what a NAS is. Thanks for the link, that's what I needed.